# How to get byte[] from IntPtr in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, intptr

I want to pass a `IntPtr` to a method takes a `byte[]` Parameter in c#. Is that possible and if it is possible how can I do that?

thx

Comment: I have a job that copies around 50 TB of data to a SQL VDI. If I could wrap that unmanaged pointer with a temporary managed byte[] array, and save the extra copy, yeah, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) method.

```
byte[] managedArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(managedArray[0]) * managedArray.Length;
IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.Copy(pnt, managedArray, 0 , managedArray.Length);
```

Comment: Is `Dump` an extension method of yours? The line containing that method should probably be deleted.

Comment: @Rest Wing: Sorry thats from Linq-Pad :)

Comment: Don't you think he means the other way around? He has an IntPtr pointing to data and he wants to pass it into a function declared with a byte[] parameter?